# PowerShell e-mail - sending .csv in body with HTML

Tags: html, email, powershell, csv

I have a powershell script that runs a mysql query, and exports the output to a .csv file.

It then imports it, sends it to a `$body` variable and e-mails it.

Here is the code

```
### Script to write body of e-mail to $body variable ###

$body = @"
CHECK 4A - MONTH DATABASE REPORT

Row count should be between 3-4k, but less on a Monday.

"@  + (Import-CSV  C:\Users\*****\Documents\Reports\result4A.csv | Out-String)
```

I want to use a bit of HTML in the e-mail too, just to make it a bit easier to read, so I used the `-BodyAsHtml` parameter:

```
### Send e-mail ###

send-mailmessage -from " Daily Check <server@company.com>" -to "Admin <e-mail@company.com>" -BodyAsHtml -subject "Daily Server Checks Report" -body "$body" -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer **.*.*.**
```

The problem is that this means the .csv file isn't displayed correctly in the e-mail, as the e-mail body is changed to HTML. Is there any way around this? I would like to keep the export to .csv solution if possible.

Comment: See [Get data from text file and send an email in table format](//stackoverflow.com/a/36375236)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$csvHTML = Import-Csv C:\Users\*****\Documents\Reports\result4A.csv  | ConvertTo-Html

$body = @"
    ....  
"@ + ($csvHTML[5..($csvHTML.length-2)] | Out-String)
```

This will convert the `CSV` file to `HTML`. Then you can simply select `<table></table>` tags that contain the CSV (skip first 5 and last 2 lines) and add it to the body of your email.

Comment: That works perfectly, but can I just clarify as to exactly where I would put the <table></table> tags? I'm having trouble making them work properly

Comment: @Ricky You don't need to put any `<table>` tags in as they will be include in the variable `$csvHTML` already.